# Consuming reactor mono incrementally

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I've a below API that returns a Mono. Since the result can be huge, server does some work and returns partial result. To get all the results I need to get token from Result and set it on Request object and send the new request untill `Result.token` is `null`.

`Mono<Result> get(Request request)`

This is how it can be done in synchronous API that returns only Result.

```
Request request = new Request();
do {
     Result result = get(request); //send to remote server
     //process result
     for(String value: result.getData()) {
         //process value
     }   
     request.token = result.getToken(); //set token on request
} while(request.getToken() != null)
```

How can I achieve the same using `Mono<Result>`? Result has main data in List and some additional metadata.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the specific problem you have. If possible add a [mcve] of the problem you have. You can use `block()` or `blockOptional()` to get the value from the `Mono` instance.

Comment: It seems that you may use a Generator or implement a Publisher